# Extracting a specific substring in C

Tags: c, strings, array

I have a string like this:

```
char buffer[] = "blablabla$GPTXT->SOME CODES HERE<-\r\n$GPRMCblablabla";
```

It is sent from an external device and changes every 1 second.

The string length is over 1000 bytes and consisted of some standard sentences beginning with "$GPXXX" and ending with CRLF. I've written the following function to extract a specific sentence:

```
int findString(char *src, char *dst, int desLen, char *what2find, char termChar)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = strstr(src, what2find); ;
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        temp += strlen(what2find);
    int j = 0;
    while (j<(desLen-1))
    {
        if (temp[j]==termChar)
            break;
        dst[j]= temp[j];
        j++;
    }
    dst[j] = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```

So:

```
 int main()
 {
  char buffer[] =       
  "$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47\r\n
  $GPGSA,A,3,04,05,,09,12,,,24,,,,,2.5,1.3,2.1*39\r\n
  $GPGSV,2,1,08,01,40,083,46,02,17,308,41,12,07,344,39,14,22,228,45*75\r\n
  $GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A\r\n
  $GPVTG,054.7,T,034.4,M,005.5,N,010.2,K*48\r\n";

  char dst[50];
  findString(buffer,dst,50,"$GPTXT",'$');
 }
```

finds and return the desired sentence.

But this code has the following problems:

1. It is very heuristic. I wonder if there exists some better solutions.
2. It depends on a character (i.e. '$') for termination. It may terminate after finding a '$' but not "$GPXXX". The optimal solution may find the characters between two strings, e.g. "$GPTXT" and "$GPRMC". I don't know if it is optimally achievable.

Note that the host processor is a 4Mhz ARM MCU!

P.S: The above-mentioned function works fine in my project. I just want to widen my C programming knowledge!

P.S. 2: Both answers from Lundin and David C. Rankin are nice. Unfortunately I can not accept both of them as answer!

Comment: 1) More examples would help convey your goal.  2) Although `src` is 1000s long, provide details about pre-"blablabla", "SOME CODES HERE<", and post-"blablabla" lengths. Do they each vary in length from 0 to 1000s?  3) Are you familiar with `const` and `restrict`?

Comment: I think the key to writing the optimal function here is knowing how reliable the data is. Have you previously verified the input string, or is it just a raw buffer received from a serial bus?

Comment: @Lundin Data verification in such situations is often done after the fact. Either the result is useful, or it isn't, but a result you will get.

Comment: @chux For example the src length is 1000. It is consisted of 10 sentences with 100 bytes length. I mean the src length is the sum of sentences' lengths. But everything may vary with time. For example one sentence may be 110 characters and another may become 90. The total is always the src length.

Comment: @Lundin Data is raw. We receive it over serial bus.

Comment: @chux I know about const but not restrict.

Comment: A complete example, with `main()`, would help.  Something that populates the argument to `int findString(char *src, char *dst, int desLen, char *what2find, char termChar)` and indicates the expected result.

Comment: @chux I just edited the main post.

Comment: "I wonder if there exists some better solutions" - perhaps you should wonder if there is a language more suited to string manipulation (hint: most of them). I mean this quite seriously; choose the right tool for the job

Comment: @Mawg The code in implemented on micro-controller. C is the most popular language. Unfortunately the choices are very limited.

Comment: I feel your pain. Personally, I would go with Python, if available, although Lua has much smaller footprint. Good luck, though, whatever you choose :-)

Comment: Well, if you are looking for speed, then `strstr` is your enemy because it returns a pointer to the beginning of the match, but you want the end (this would have saved you one `strlen`). Another problem: copying one character at a time, don't do this, if speed is important, use `memcpy` instead. Also, everything that can be const needs to be const, this helps compilers generate faster code, in your case, the `src` and `what2find` should be const.

Comment: Although not directly relevant to your specific question, it appears the data you're parsing is an NMEA GPS stream. While writing a parser is a good exercise, I'd recommend using the fantastically simple [libnmea](http://nmea.io/) in production.

Comment: Don't write lexical analyzers in C.  Use (f)lex.  (Assuming there isn't, as above, an existing library for the task.)

Comment: @MTcoster Nice library. I reviewed it. I think I should make some changes to import it in my ARM project. I've nearly implemented the parser.

Comment: @MTCoster and moreover, my receiver sends all sentences at once. So I should first seperate them and then use these libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as performance goes, there isn't much you can improve without doing manual optimization tricks. Such things are already implemented in the library functions though.

The main issue I see here is that you copy data into the destination before you know if the string actually contains a termination character. By doing so, you save a bit of time as you can copy and search at the same time. But you also end up copying data before the input has been verified.

What's best in your case, I don't know. It depends on how reliable your input is. If you have already verified it previously, then your copy+check in one might be the best choice. If it's some raw data from a serial bus (UART etc), it might be wisest to verify the data before you copy. I will show a version that does the verification first, it will be safer although possibly slightly slower than what you currently have.

---

General code review:

Style/best practices

- Pointer parameters to data that isn't modified should be `const` qualified.
- Using a plain `int` for error handling isn't ideal. You actually have several possible errors here: missing search string, missing terminator, potential buffer overflow. Even if your program doesn't need to know what went wrong, it might ease debugging and it costs you nothing extra to add.
- The while loop could have been replaced with a for loop, for better readability:

  ```
  for(size_t i=0; i<desLen-1; i++)
  {
    if(temp[i]==termChar)
    {
      break;
    }
    dst[i]=temp[i];
  }
  ```

Performance

- The length of the search key could be determined at compile-time.
- Consider dropping the terminating character parameter if `what2find[0]` could be said to always contain it.
- Some micro-optimizations with C99 `restrict` are possible. I'll show an example below.

---

Here is a different version which contains more detailed error handling and checks for termination before copy:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum
{
  STRFIND_OK,
  STRFIND_KEY_NOT_FOUND,
  STRFIND_TERMINATOR_NOT_FOUND,
  STRFIND_BUFFER_OVERFLOW,
} strfind_result_t;

strfind_result_t strfind_cpy (const char* str, 
                              size_t      key_size,
                              const char  key[key_size], 
                              char        terminator,
                              size_t      dst_size, 
                              char        dst [dst_size])
{
  char* start = strstr(str, key);
  if(start == NULL)
  {
    return STRFIND_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
  }

  start += key_size-1;
  char* end = strchr(start, terminator);
  if(end == NULL)
  {
    return STRFIND_TERMINATOR_NOT_FOUND;
  }

  size_t length = (size_t)(end-start);
  if(length+1 > dst_size)
  {
    return STRFIND_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
  }

  memcpy(dst, start, length);
  dst[length] = '\0';

  return STRFIND_OK;
}
```

C99 pointer-to-VLA are used to ensure data size integrity of the buffers. If the verification of data isn't needed, `strchr` could be replaced with a for loop like the one demonstrated above.

`memcpy` is the fastest possible copy. It will be faster than copy character-by-character, since the library implementation will work on 32 bit chunks that your ARM likes better than copying individual bytes. So my code might actually be faster (or it may be slower), you'll have to benchmark it.

Further micro-optimization is possible with C99 restrict:

```
strfind_result_t strfind_cpy (const char* restrict  str, 
                              size_t                key_size,
                              const char* restrict  key, 
                              char                  terminator,
                              size_t                dst_size, 
                              char* restrict        dst);
```

This tells the compiler that none of the pointers passed point at the same buffer. This may improve performance ever so slightly, depending on how your compiler handles pointer aliasing internally. Check the disassembled code to see if `restrict` gave any benefits.

---

Example of use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  const char data[] = "blablabla$GPTXT->SOME CODES HERE<-\r\n$GPRMCblablabla";
  char buf[50];
  strfind_result_t result;

  result = strfind_cpy(data,
                       sizeof "$GPTXT",
                       "$GPTXT",
                       '$',
                       sizeof buf,
                       buf);

  if(result == STRFIND_OK)
  {
    puts(buf);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. What if I use two "strstr"s:

      find = strstr(buffer,"$GPTXT")+ strlen("$GPTXT");
      find1= strstr(buffer,"$GPRMC");
      strncpy(dst,find,(int)(find1-find));
      dst[(int)(find1-find)] = '\0';

Comment: @ImanH Well, if you need to use a second strstr that's another question, but it is very similar to this. You should however not use `strncpy` for any purpose, it is both slow and dangerous. `memcpy` is superior to it in every single way. See [Which functions from the standard library must (should) be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518)

Comment: So I can solve the second problem I mentioned above, in this way.

Comment: @ImanH Yeah sure, just replace the terminator parameter with a second search key parameter.

Comment: I’m confused by your recommendation to use VLA parameters. I was under the impression that the consensus was not to use them, since their sizes are not enforced by the compiler, and thus misleading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There is nothing preventing the compiler from doing a check when the parameters are compile-time constants. And static analysers may be able to do such a check even when the compiler is not. But mostly the purpose is self-documenting code. Though if you use this style, you have the option to code the type safety yourself. See https://godbolt.org/z/LTOCGY for an example. This also assuming the size is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 5):

While you have a good presentation of your question, it is still a bit unclear exactly what you are looking to extract between `$GPTXT` and `'$'` given that you have the `"\r\n"` prior to the terminating `'$'`. It seems unlikely that you would want to retain the *carriage return/line feed* as part of your returned substring. My best interpretation is that you want `"->SOME CODES HERE<-"` extracted from the string (drop a comment if this is incorrect).

If this is the case, you can use the `\r\n` to your advantage in *tokenizing* the string to return that part between `$GPTXT` and `"\r\n$"` by using `"\r\n$"` as the delimiters passed to `strtok`. The only additional task needed in your `findstr` function would be to step past your search string before calling `strtok`.

In looking at the declaration for `findstring`, I would tweak the parameters just a bit to make them consistent with most of the other string library functions. That being to reverse the source and dest parameters such that `dest` comes before `src` as in `strcpy, etc...` I'm not a fan of one way over the other, but I have found keeping functions at least as consistent as possible helps avoid inadvertent parameter swaps.

I would also change your `termChar` to a `const char*` parameter to allow flexibility in passing the delimiter to use with `strtok`.

An implementation might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TERM   32
#define MAXC 1024
#define DELIM "\r\n$"

char *findstr (char *dest, const char *src, size_t len, const char *srch,
                const char *delim)
{
    char *p = strstr (src, srch);   /* locate beginning of search in src */
    size_t toklen = 0;              /* token length to calculate once */

    if (!p)                         /* validate or return NULL */
        return NULL;

    p += strlen (srch);             /* step past search str */

    /* tokenize p based on delim and validate length < len */
    if ((p = strtok (p, delim)) && (toklen = strlen(p)) < len)
        memcpy (dest, p, toklen+1); /* copy to dest w/nul-char */
    else
        return NULL;                /* or return NULL */

    return dest;
}

int main (void) {

    char buffer[] = "blablabla$GPTXT->SOME CODES HERE<-\r\n$GPRMCblablabla";
    char sub[MAXC] = "";

    if (findstr (sub, buffer, MAXC, "GPTXT", DELIM))
        printf ("sub: '%s'\n", sub);
}
```

(**note:** since you have already scanned to length of your token to validate it is less than `len`, there is no need to scan again by using `strcpy` to effect the token copy to `dest`, simply using `memcpy` will provide an ever-so-slightly more efficient copy)

**Example Use/Output**

While provides:

```
$ ./bin/findstr
sub: '->SOME CODES HERE<-'
```

If you are looking to parse something slightly different, let me know.

Comment: My take is that the input could either come from another device ("AT commands") or from a RS-232 terminal PC tool. In the latter case the CR+LF, or just LF, might be appended mostly as an annoying side-effect. I guess in that case they should just be discarded, rather than to use as part of the search key. Because another device is not likely to send them, unless it is part of some protocol specification.

Comment: That makes the most sense. I was scratching my head on the reason they would be embedded (and cussing windoze at the same time). I guess they could be read from some port, but that raises the issue of whether an accumulator buffer should be employed to insure a complete line is read and not just the first-half, etc..

Comment: In my special use case, the CRLF must be always sent . So the format of sentences are always "$GPxxx______\r\n". But in some cases the sender, unfortunately randomly, does not send CR or LF.

Comment: And, I can implement an interrupt method for UART receiving to parse the input while getting data. But such calculations are not suggested in interrupt routine.

Comment: You are still covered with `strtok()` regardless of whether `"\r\n"` is sent, so long as you include `'$'` as part of the delimiter as well. `strtok()` will parse the token based on the first delimiter located. But yes, in an interrupt you would not want to rely on a returned value. The type can be change by to `int` without any loss of functionality and since `dest` is filled within the function there is no need for a return.

Comment: All of this can be done manually as well without `strtok`. It just walks a pointer down the buffer beginning at `p` looking for the next `'\r'` `'\n'` or `'$'`. So rather than using `strtok`, you could simply use a second pointer (say `char *ep;` to use as an end pointer) and then set `ep = p;` and iterate with `ep` until  one of your delimiter characters is reached and then use a `memcpy (des, src, ep - p);`

Answer (score 5):

Although it's not mentioned in the question, it appears that you're receiving NMEA 0183 sentences.  There are libraries (including free, open-source ones) for parsing such inputs, so I'm surprised to see hand-built code here.  I recommend you **choose a good library, and completely reimplement the code** using the library.

---

Assuming you can't use any of the libraries for some reason, I'll continue with review.

You probably only want to recognise `what2find` at the start of a line, rather than in any other positions in the string.  Although it's unlikely, it's possible that it appears (perhaps in a sentence that includes an arbitrary label or comment field).

There are serious problems with the test program - specifically the multi-line string literal.  I'm guessing from knowledge of the format that the sentences should all start at beginning of line:

```
char buffer[] =
    "$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47\r\n"
    "$GPGSA,A,3,04,05,,09,12,,,24,,,,,2.5,1.3,2.1*39\r\n"
    "$GPGSV,2,1,08,01,40,083,46,02,17,308,41,12,07,344,39,14,22,228,45*75\r\n"
    "$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A\r\n"
    "$GPVTG,054.7,T,034.4,M,005.5,N,010.2,K*48\r\n";
```

This also shows a problem with the interface - is it necessary to require the input be modifiable?  It seems reasonable that I should be able to pass a pointer to constant chars, and the example itself shows `what2find` being passed a string literal (which is necessarily `const char*`.  It's also clearer for the reader if you write the destination capacity as `sizeof dst` rather than as literal `50`.

Test should also perform a search for a sentence that exists in the input - at the moment, test coverage is very low.

Consider returning position and length of the result, and let the caller decide whether or not to copy.  Alternatively, accept pointer to writeable characters, and null-terminate in-place - but note that that may preclude calling the function several times on the same data; it's more suited to line-by-line processing, perhaps with a callback for each sentence data type.

If you do need to copy within the function, there's no need to write your own `strncpy()` function.

Rename `temp` to something more descriptive; remove the empty statement following, and change `if`/`return`/`else` to plain `if`/`return`:

```
int findString(const char *src, char *dst, size_t desLen,
               const char *what2find, char termChar)
{
    char *start = strstr(src, what2find);
    if (!start) { return 0; }

    start += strlen(what2find);
    char *end = strchr(start, '\r');
    size_t length = end - start;
    if (length + 1 > desLen) { return 0; }

    memcpy(dst, start, length);
    dst[length] = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```